# Error in getting row count using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to get the row count of grid view using javascript. Javascript is called but some how I am not getting row count. This is the code for my javascript

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function CheckSites() {

    var Grid = document.getElementByID(<%=grdSiteInformation.ClientID%>);
    var row = Grid.rows.length;
    alert(grid);
if(length=0)
    alert('Enter atleast one site');
    }
</script>
```

This is how I am calling that function...

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" OnClientClick="CheckSites()"/>
```

This is the definition of my gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdSiteInformation" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        OnRowCommand="grdSiteInformation_RowCommand">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="TableRowIndex" HeaderText="Sr.No" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="SiteID" HeaderText="SiteID" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="POrderID" HeaderText="POrderID" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="SiteName" HeaderText="SiteName" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Location" HeaderText="Location" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="SiteAddress" HeaderText="SiteAddress" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Cluster" HeaderText="Cluster" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="SubVendorName" HeaderText="SubVendorName" />
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("SiteID") %>' CommandName="Edt"
                                        Text="Edit" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    Edit
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

Please guide me where/what I am making mistake mistake...

Thanks

Comment: which gridview you are using, Is it asp.net gridview or third part control ?

Comment: What HTML element do you have in Grid? Is it a <table>?

Comment: put == (equality operator) to compare values.

Comment: @Jeevan Bhatt..Yes it is asp.net gridview..

Comment: is solution work for you

Comment: Not working any solutions provided as an answer for this question

Comment: @Chirag Fanse - try jquery solution if possible and dont forget to mark answer as accpeted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var rowCount = document.getElementById('<%=grdSiteInformation.ClientID%>')
       .getElementsByTagName("TR").length;
alert(rowCount);
```

**Edit**

Try jQuery

```
var totalRows = $("#<%=GridView1.ClientID %> tr").length;
```

Comment: @ Pranay Rana..Not getting any error but when I kept watch,I saw the control skips the var rowCoubnt....

Comment: @Chirag Fanse - try jquery solution if possible

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Asp.Net's GridView and you just want row count then you can change your js function as:

```
function CheckSites() 
{    
    var row = <%=grdSiteInformation.Rows.Count %>    
    if(row=0)
    alert('Enter at least one site');
}
```

Comment: Hmm i create same scenario in my local system and its working fine, are you getting any exception/error ?